# Change cursor to hyperlink hand in ms-access on all buttons

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a lot of buttons and don't wish to search for all of them.
So I guess there are 2 parts. How do loop through and apply this to only button controls and what property can I change to change the hover behavior.

I have tried the following.

```
Private Sub Report_Load()
Dim cc As Control
           For Each cc In Me.Controls
                   If InStr(LCase(cc.Name), "command") > 0 
                   cc.hover = "hyperlink hand"
                   End If
           Next cc
```

[image: cursor on hover]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. The reason it might trip you up is the autocomplete might not help you, but it still worked so long all all buttons start with the work command. (which sometimes they might not so watch out!)

```
Dim cc As Control
           For Each cc In Me.Controls
                   If cc.ControlType = acCommandButton Then
                   cc.QuickStyle = 9
                   cc.CursorOnHover = acCursorOnHoverHyperlinkHand
                   End If
           Next cc
```

Comment: Suggest you ignore the control's name and check its type instead:  `If cc.ControlType = acCommandButton Then` ...